# Поменять символы в строке местами

Tags: c#, строки

Необходимо ввести через Writeline строку и используя процедуру поменять символы местами наоборот, например:

Входная строка = abc123

Результат работы программы = 321cba

Comment: И в чём у вас возникли трудности?

Comment: По какому критерию менять-то нужно? Дополните вопрос. Заменить конкретные последовательности, или просто сделать реверс?

Comment: Задача в **общем случае** не такая уж простая http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029238/reverse-a-string-with-accent-chars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Более элегантное и не такое накладное решение, чем у предыдущего ответчика, с использованием *StringBuilder*:

```
var a1 = "abc123";
var sb = new StringBuilder();
//В цикле мы начинаем читать элементы строки с конца.
for (int i = a1.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
{                
    sb.Append(a1[i]);
}
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString()); //321cba
Console.ReadLine();
```

Или вариант по короче с использованием массивов:

```
var a1 = "abc123";
var a1_reverse = a1.ToCharArray().Reverse();
Console.WriteLine(new string(a1_reverse.ToArray())); //321cba
Console.ReadLine();
```

Поскольку метод **Reverse()** возвращает `IEnumerable<T>` (в данном случае `IEnumerable<char>`, то для создания строки его нужно привести к массиву методом **ToArray()** и из массива символов уже создать строку.

Если Вам нужно сделать отдельную процедуру (метод) для этого - все просто:

```
public static string StringReverse(string a1){
/*
* Вставьте сюда код из первого или второго варианта, что я предложил.
*/
}
```

Или же Вы можете сделать расширяемый (extension) метод, который можно будет вызывать прямо на переменной класса **string** везде, где вы подключите (using) класс с этим методом:

```
public static string StringReversExt(this string a1){
/*
* Вставьте сюда код из первого или второго варианта, что я предложил.
*/
}
```

Теперь можно вызывать этот метод примерно так:

```
string a1 = "abc123";
Console.WriteLine(a1.StringReverseExt());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Более подробную информацию об расширяемых методах можно почитать, скажем, на [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb383977.aspx).

Удачи!

Answer (score -1):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите строку");
            //var a1 = "abc123";
            var a1 = Console.ReadLine();

            var length = a1.Length;
            var a2 = "";
            for (int i = length; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                a2 += a1[i-1];
            }
            Console.WriteLine(a2);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Очень неэффективное решение!  Конкатенировать строки в цикле - плохая идея, так как строки  в .NET относятся к immutable объектам. На каждой итерации цикла будет создана новая строка, и затем она будет нуждаться в сборке мусора, что создаст ненужные накладные расходы. Чтобы этого избежать нужно использовать класс [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.7) и его метод `Append`.